# Why does Selenium appends a back slash to the dot (.) character resulting into (\.) for the value of ID attribute that has a (.) in it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to get an element by ID with selenium in JAVA. The ID of the element in question so happens to have a period in it `id="myprojectId0.123456789"` when I try to find the element like so

```
WebElement projId = driver.findElement(By.id("mprojectId0.10724909303153396"));
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #mprojectId0\.10724909303153396
```

For some reason the `.` character within the value of the *ID* attribute is being converted to `\.` and hence it cannot find the element. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why it is behaving like this until see the application.However you can try following xpath `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'myprojectId0')]"))`

Comment: `.` is a special character and should be escaped, `#mprojectId0\.10724909303153396`correct one. There's another reason why you're not able to locate the element. Check if the element inside `iframe` and try with explicit wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is pretty much justified and as expected. As per the discussion in [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) `By.id` is translated by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) into it's equivalent **`By.cssSelector`** and as the **`.`** character is a special character, it is automatically **escaped** by a *backslash* i.e. **`\`**. Hence:

```
By.id("mprojectId0.10724909303153396")
```

gets translated into

```
By.cssSelector("#mprojectId0\.10724909303153396")
```

---

### Solution

However the value of the `id` *attribute* i.e. **`mprojectId0.10724909303153396`** looks dynamic to me and would change everytime the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) gets rendered. Accordingly you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following dynamic *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement projId = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[id^='mprojectId']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement projId = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'mprojectId')]")));
  ```

Comment: You are correct. Having read the documentation, it makes sense to almost always use the `By.cssSelector` to select the element. Plus, I didn't realize that the ID I was trying to select was dynamically generated. I stuck to using the `By.xpath`