# Web Scraping with Python Selenium performance

Tags: python, performance, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

According to performance it is more than obvious that web scraping with BautifulSoup is much faster than using a webdriver with Selenium. However I don't know any other way to get content from a dynamic web page. I thought the difference comes from the time needed for the browser to load elements but it is definitely more than that. Once the browser loads the page(5 seconds) all I had to do is to extract some `<tr>` tags from a table. It took about 3-4 minutes to extract 1016 records which is extremely slow in my opinion. I came to a conclusion that webdriver methods for finding elements such as `find_elements_by_name` are slow. Is `find_elements_by`.. from webdriver much slower than the `find` method in BeautifulSoup? And would it be faster if I get the whole html from the webdriver browser and then parse it with lxml and use the BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Yes you can get whole html by using `driver.page_source`

Comment: Yes but is it confirmed that BeautifulSoup find is faster than the one in Selenium?

Comment: Yes thats true. BeautifulSoup is much faster than Selenium

Comment: I tried parsing driver.page_source with BeautifulSoup and it was much faster less than 10 seconds compared to the previous 3-4 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it would be much faster to use Selenium only to get the HTML after waiting for the page to be ready and then use BeautifulSoup or lxml to parse that HTML.

Another option could be to use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) either only to get the HTML or to get the info that you want directly. It should also be faster than Selenium. There are some unofficial python bindings for it: [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/)

Answer (score 1):

[Web Scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869382/scraping-contents-of-multi-web-pages-of-a-website-using-beautifulsoup-and-seleni/47871704#47871704) using either with [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) or [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) should be a part of the *testing strategy*. Putting it straight if your intent is to scrape the static content *BeautifulSoup* is unmatched. But incase the website content is dynamically rendered *Selenium* is the way to go.

Having said that, *BeautifulSoup* won't wait for the dynamic content which isn't readily present in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) once page loading completes. Where as using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have [*Implicit Wait* and *Explicit Wait*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518467/how-to-properly-configure-implicit-explicit-waits-and-pageloadtimeout-through/50524225#50524225) at your disposal to locate the desired dynamic elements.

Finally, `find_elements_by_name()` may be delta expensive in terms of performance as *Selenium* translates it into it's equivalent **`find_element_by_css_selector()`**. You can find some more details in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929595/why-does-selenium-appends-a-back-slash-to-the-dot-character-resulting-into/57930846#57930846)

---

### Outro

[Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

Answer (score 1):

Look into 2 options:

1) sometimes these dynamic pages do actually have the data within `<script>` tags in a valid json format. You can use `requests` to get the html, beautifulsoup will get the `<script>` tag, then you can use `json,loads()` to parse.

2) go directly to the source. Look at the dev tools and search the XHR to see if you can go directly to the url/API and that generates the data and return the data that way (most likely again in json format). In my opinion, this is by far the better/faster option if available.

If you can provide the url, I can check to see if either of these options apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try evaluating in javascript. For example this:

```
item = driver.execute_script("""return {
  div: document.querySelector('div').innerText,
  h2: document.querySelector('h2').innerText
}""")
```

will be at least 10x faster than this:

```
item = {
  "div": driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div').text,
  "h2": driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2').text
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if it was faster than BS a lot of the time too.

Comment: Hello, @pguardiario
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75858506/how-can-i-click-confirm-button-in-python-capmonster
could you give me tip for this one, please?