# How can I click confirm button in python-capmonster

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

Everyone
How are you?
Now I am making the script to solve the recaptcha.
Using python-capmonster module, I can get response. so I inputted the response in `<Textarea>` tag.

`driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "%s"' % response)`

I can see it inputted correctly in textarea at selenium's browser.

but where is submit button? how can I click submit button?

That is my question. Will I need to click the submit(verify or skip) button in `<iframe>`?

It's really up in the air.

If you know some tip for this one, please help me.
Thanks

To check step, please check this one.
https://www.tixr.com/groups/beakandskiff/events/rainbow-kitten-surprise-60724
(click vip experience, increase amount and checkout, if you can meet recaptcha in the site)

Comment: @all, is there any help for me?

Comment: @all, I add bounty for this problem, but I didn't get solution yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for visiting this problem.
For solve problem, I tried to bounty to solve the problem. but I get correctly answer. I can get correctly answer from zennolab.com.

I found this problem using `callback` function. and submit button is hidden in `callback` function.
For this problem, I discussed with ZennoLab.com stuff.
finally I found the solution using 2captcha-python module.
For refer this problem, I write down links below.

```
https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#invisible
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible
https://github.com/2captcha/2captcha-python.git
https://pypi.org/project/2captcha-python/
https://2captcha.com/demo/recaptcha-v2-invisible?level=low
```

Thanks for your attantion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the captcha is initialized and submitted via a javascript function. First of all, you can try the submit the textarea's form manually. If this doesn't work, you have to find the initializer (maybe not exist) or submit function in javascript files.

Comment: Hello, @alp, could you tell me more in details?

Comment: currently I can get captcha token using python-capmonster module, and input in textarea which has classname is `g-recaptcha-response`. now I have no way to click the submit. That is my point

Answer (score 0):

You can try to submit the form by triggering the form's submit event using JavaScript. Something like this:

```
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Submit')]")
submit_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();")
```

Comment: Hello, @angwrk
Did you check offered url in question? As you can see, there is no submit button